# Adding photo background via VS Code

Tags: html, css, background-image

May I ask on how to add photo background on my website using VS Code?

I tried checking in yt but its not background, it just add up to my website as photo alone.

Comment: Any CSS tutorial should have pointed you to the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) property. And VS Code isn't really relevant here.

Comment: if you search the WEB for `CSS background image` you get a lot of useful sites, MDN is a very good one

Answer (score 0):

In css:-
background-imge:url("");

i think this maybe helpful for everyone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#### using css background-image: url("url") // it is the best practice

###### but you will have to also set some addtional css properties like

```css
.div{
background-image: url("../images/demo.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 300px 400px;
background-origin: content-box;
background-position: center;
}
```

try these
the url can be a link to some hosted image file or
it can be a local image as showed in the example try these

Accept the answer if this helps